# Get specific keys only and neglect others while parsing JSON string (No framework libraries)

Tags: javascript, json

I have an object string like:

```
my_object_string = `{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5",
    "key6": "value6",
    "key7": "value7",
    "key8": "value8"
}`;
```

And if I want to parse the whole object I will use:

```
my_object = JSON.parse(my_object_string); // Stores object with all key-value pairs from key1 to key8
```

What I need to do is to store just specific keys and neglect the others while parsing.

I tried reviver function to get only key2, key5 and key8 but it doesn't work correctly:

```
my_object = JSON.parse(my_object_string, (key, value) => 
  /(?:key2)|(?:key5)|(?:key8)/.test(key)
    ? value
    : null
);
```

The resulted object I'm trying to get should look like:

```
my_object = {
    "key2": "value2",
    "key5": "value5",
    "key8": "value8"
};
```

I want to use only basic JavaScript code (without using framework libraries). Also play within the reviver function in `JSON.parse(text, reviver)` only in order to get specific keys.

Comment: The `JSON` is not valid

Comment: your Regex is flawed

Comment: your problem is obvious if you add some debugging console.logs - you should also return `undefined` rather than `null` - I wouldn't recommend doing this, but this works `JSON.parse(my_object_string, (key, value) => (typeof value != 'string' || /^key[258]$/.test(key)) ? value : undefined);`

Comment: I've fixed them now (JSON & used RegEx). Sorry I've not tested the examples I added before posting.

Comment: @JaromandaX—maybe replace `typeof value != 'string'` with `!key` (ooh that's dirty…). ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Last key passed to reviver function is empty because it corresponds to whole object, so in your case you should return it without changing. Also you can use arrays indexOf method instead of regexp.

```
var my_object = {
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3",
  "key4": "value4",
  "key5": "value5",
  "key6": "value6",
  "key7": "value7",
  "key8": "value8"
};
var my_object_string = JSON.stringify(my_object);

var keys = ['key2', 'key5', 'key8'];
var my_object2 = JSON.parse(my_object_string, function(k,v){
  if (k) {
    return keys.indexOf(k) !== -1 ? v : undefined;
  }
  else {
    // no key means root object
    return v;
  }
});
console.log(my_object2);
```

Comment: This is the actual answer: "*Last key passed to reviver function is empty because it corresponds to whole object*", hence the OP's reviver doesn't work. That isn't obvious [*from the spec*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-json.parse).

Comment: @RobG If the specification is not obviously clear to you as to `JSON.parse()` algorithm you should indicate the same the authors of the spec.

Comment: @guest271314—if I was to write to the authors about every part of the spec that I found unclear I'd be writing a lot of emails!! The confusing part is that the reviver "*… is called with each of the key/value pairs produced by the parse*", which should go on to say "…and lastly with the object itself as the value and "" (empty string) as the key".

Answer (score 3):

Use valid `JSON`, adjust `RegExp` to `/key1|key3|key4|key6|key7/`, return `void 0`: `undefined` if `.test()` returns `true`

```js
var my_object_string = `{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
    "key5": "value5",
    "key6": "value6",
    "key7": "value7",
    "key8": "value8"
}`;

var rev = (key, value) => /key1|key3|key4|key6|key7/.test(key) ? void 0 : value;

var my_object = JSON.parse(my_object_string, rev);

console.log(my_object);
```

Comment: While this achieves the required outcome, it doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work. Bartosz Matuszewski's answer does.

Comment: @RobG You deleted your initial comment, then deleted response comment. The JSON still has to be valid.

Comment: Yes, a bit of edit/comment confusion. ;-) The other issues were fixed in the OP, the main issue for me is that the object itself is passed to the reviver, so fails the test. Yours works because the test is reversed (i.e. you're looking for keys to delete rather than those to keep).

Comment: It's not working when I use

`var rev_keep = (key, value) => /key2|key5|key8/.test(key) ? value : void 0;`

`var my_object = JSON.parse(my_object_string, rev_keep);`.
It's weird. Why this happens?

Comment: @Omar Read [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48333058/) by Bartosz Matuszewski and comments and the linked specification

Comment: @guest271314 I understand now. The problem is in the last key which stands for the whole object. This what should it be in order to be safe `rev_keep = (key, value) => (key) ? (/key2|key5|key8/.test(key) ? value : void 0) : value;` `JSON.parse(my_object_string, rev_keep);` and `rev_discard = (key, value) => (key) ? (/key1|key3|key4|key6|key7/.test(key) ? void 0 : value) : value;` `JSON.parse(my_object_string, rev_discard);`